# priority queue based on 2-3-4 tree structure

Tags: math, data-structures, tree, priority-queue

Does anybody have any information about `priority queues` based on the `2-4 tree structure`? 
I have been searching all day.. 
Any references from anyone who knows would be really appreciated..
Thank you.

Comment: Is this related to [min-max heaps](http://www.diku.dk/forskning/performance-engineering/Jesper/heaplab/heapsurvey_html/node11.html)?

Comment: @finnw: not directly. Priority queues can be implemented using any standard ordered search data structure (2-3-4 trees, BSTs, red-black trees, etc.). The structure you link to is a specialized data structure for this problem.

Comment: Very interesting and rare data structure. I read the CLRS book 'Introduction to Algorithms'. 2-4 trees are very explained very good. I guess each leaf has to hold only one value in the queue though..

Comment: @larsmans do you have any book in mind that could help me?

Comment: If you have a good description of 2-3-4 trees, that should suffice. You don't need to change the structure, just implement `delete_minimum` and use the trees in a slightly different way than usual. Note: you may want to allow duplicate keys, since several items may have the same priority.

Answer (score 1):

1. Implement 2-3-4 trees, allowing duplicate keys.
2. Use them as priority queues by storing priorities as keys and implementing retrieve+delete minimum (or maximum) element. The minimum can be found by following the lefmost child pointer until it becomes null.

See also [tree sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_sort).